# Credit card expiration dates - Inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: e-commerce, payment

Say you've got a credit card number with an expiration date of 05/08 - i.e. May 2008.

Does that mean the card expires on the morning of the 1st of May 2008, or the night of the 31st of May 2008?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

It took me a couple of minutes to find a site that I could source for this.

> The card is valid until the last day of the month indicated, after the last [sic]<sup>1</sup>
>   day of the next month; the card cannot be used to make a purchase if the
>   merchant attempts to obtain an authorization. 
>   - [Source](http://web.archive.org/web/20081003052424/http://cumemberscard.com/noda/CreditCardGlossary.asp)

Also, while looking this up, I found an interesting article on Microsoft's website using an example like this, exec summary: [Access 2000 for a month/year defaults to the first day of the month, here's how to override that to calculate the end of the month like you'd want for a credit card](https://web.archive.org/web/20150113060002/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210534).

Additionally, this page has [everything you ever wanted to know about credit cards](http://euro.ecom.cmu.edu/resources/elibrary/everycc.htm).

---

1. This is assumed to be a typo and that it should read "..., after the first day of the next month; ..."

Comment: from @rob below:
I would have to double check, but I think it applies more to transactions that haven't cleared yet as opposed to new purchases. Since you can use the card through the end of the month, their might be some transactions that are still pending when the physical card expires.

Comment: @Coronatus - The site that I got the original quote from seems to have changed the link, but I think they meant for that to say "after the first day of the next month."

Comment: Thankfully, I had 1 credit card which actually printed the full date (ie: the last day of the month). I still had to wonder whether it worked for the entirety of the last day, but it was at least useful.

Comment: ""after the first day of the next month."" would mean that the first day itself would be considered OK, which is probably wrong.

Comment: @donbright - I've updated the quote with some additional commentary. Since it is a direct quote I'm assuming that they meant the first day of the next month and not the last day of the next month. From a legal standpoint, I seem to recall that that would mean that the card would expire exactly at midnight of the the last day in the expiration month.

Comment: Nice info! love the last link. The second link however does not lead to relevant content.

Comment: @GIVE-ME-CHICKEN Got to love Microsoft with their non-archiving links.

Comment: *until the last day of the month*, implies that it would not be valid *during* the last day of the month

Answer (score 16):

If you are writing a site which takes credit card numbers for payment:

1. You should probably be as permissive as possible, so that if it does expire, you allow the credit card company to catch it. So, allow it until the last second of the last day of the month.
2. Don't write your own credit card processing code. If^H^HWhen you write a bug, someone will lose real money. We all make mistakes, just don't make decisions that turn your mistakes into catastrophes.

Comment: For the uninitaited, what does `If^H^HWhen` expand to mean? :s

Comment: `^H` is a way of representing the backspace control code.

Answer (score 13):

Have a look on one of your own credit cards.  It'll have some text like `EXPIRES END` or `VALID THRU` above the date.  So the card expires at the end of the given month.

Comment: haha...good point.  i never realized that it was so explicate myself!

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, it has expired at the end of that month.  That is based on the fact that I can use it during that month, and that month is when my bank sends a new one.

Answer (score 5):

According to Visa's "[Card Acceptance and Chargeback Management Guidelines for Visa Merchants](http://usa.visa.com/download/merchants/chargeback-management-guidelines-for-visa-merchants.pdf)"; "Good Thru" (or "Valid Thru") Date is the expiration date of the card:

> A card is valid through the last day of the month shown, (e .g ., if
>   the Good Thru date is 03/12,the card is valid through March 31, 2012
>   and expires on April 1, 2012 .)

It is located below the embossed account number. **If the current transaction date is after the "Good Thru" date, the card has expired.**

Comment: +1 For visa.com source. Thanks for the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/54078/revisions) also [Royce Williams](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263879/royce-williams) (Much better to have the quote in the answer, with a link to the source).

Answer (score 4):

I process a lot of credit card transaction at work, and I can tell you that the expiry date is inclusive.

Also, I agree with Gorgapor. Don't write your own processing code. They are some good tools out there for credit card processing. Here we have been using [Monetra](http://www.mainstreetsoftworks.com/) for 3 years and it does a pretty decent job at it.

Answer (score 4):

lots of big companies dont even use your expiration date anymore because it causes auto-renewal of payments to be lost when cards are issued with new expiration dates and the same account number.  This has been a huge problem in the service industry, so these companies have cornered the card issuers into processing payments w/o expiration dates to avoid this pitfall.  Not many people know about this yet, so not all companies use this practice.

Answer (score 4):

How do time zones factor in this analysis.  Does a card expire in New York before California?  Does it depend on the billing or shipping addresses?

Answer (score 1):

I had a Automated Billing setup online and the credit card said it say good Thru 10/09, but the card was rejected the first week in October and again the next week. Each time it was rejected it cost me a $10 fee. Don't assume it good thru the end of the month if you have automatic billing setup.

Comment: I would file a complaint/bug with the payee or the automated billing provider.  One or both of them are not properly interpreting the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

In your example a credit card is expired on 6/2008.

Without knowing what you are doing I cannot say definitively you should not be validating ahead of time but be aware that sometimes business rules defy all logic.

For example, where I used to work they often did not process a card at all or would continue on transaction failure simply so they could contact the customer and get a different card.